# (La)Tex math parsing for C/C++

Tags: c++, parsing, scripting, latex

I would like to convert parse (la)tex math expressions, and convert them to (any kind of!) scripting language expression, so I can evaluate expressions.
What libraries do you recommend ?

Comment: It's quite a strange idea. How do you distinguish $a^n$ where $n$ is an index from $a^n$ which is pow(a,n)? What is \cdot in $A \cdot B$? Latex math is purely visual, it does not have any semantics.

Comment: @SKlogic: maybe this is just going to be used for expressions like `$\sqrt[4]{\frac{a+b}{2}}$`

Comment: In this case it's not obvious why using latex notation at all - a third language could be used, with translation into both latex and whatever is convenient to evaluate.

Comment: Maybe he's got no choice. Or the final objective is some kind of software that solves equations, like Mathematica.

Comment: Yep, I wouldnt ask this question if I had alternatives, doh :D

Comment: @J.B., most likely you've got a lot of alternatives, you're just not aware of their availability. Could you please explain more of a background - why do you need your source language to be TeX if in the end of a day you want evaluation? Explain the limits of your evaluation - which mathematical expressions it will serve, what is a set of functions, is it a numeric or partially symbolic evaluation? You won't get a proper answer without this information.

Comment: Perhaps you can use a tex2mathml converter and use MathML? MathML is 'plain' XML and may be easier to parse. Or at the least there are more libraries for mathml parsing

Comment: Input equations that I recieve are in tex format. My job is to evaluate expression and do something with the result. Expressions are not crazy complex math, basic math that can be calculated with any language math functions. And let's say I may convert input to MathML.

Comment: @J.B., it does not help. Please elaborate more on the background. Why your input is tex? What the "basic math" is (indexes are quite basic, see my first example)?

Comment: hello, did you find an answer? what did you do?

Comment: The use case is obvious.  With the rise of proof assistance such as Coq and Lean, clearly the asker is trying to enable their users to enter in LaTeX formulas together with English and evaluate them mathematically, i.e. enable to the computer to do math with the math.  I'm doing the same sort of thing which landed me on this question.  Ideally one day a computer should be able to read and fully parse the mathematics of a nicely enough written MSE post.

Answer (score 2):

May be it will help - take a look at [TeXmacs](http://www.texmacs.org/), especially at a way it interacts with computer algebra systems.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a set of possible options from a similar question. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4223/what-parsers-for-latex-mathematics-exist-outside-of-the-tex-engines

I think that Perl would make a fine choice for something like this, acting on text is one of its fortes.

Here is some info on how to make an exclusive flip-flop test (to find the context between \begin{} and \end{} without keeping those lines), http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/11/make-exclusive-flip-flop-operators/

EDIT: So this problem has started me going. Here is a first attempt to create something here is my "math.pl" which takes a .tex file as an arguement (i.e. `$./math.pl test.tex`).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Balanced qw/extract_multiple extract_bracketed/;

my $re_num = qr/[+\-\dE\.]/;

my $file = shift;

open( my $fh, '<', $file);

#parsing this out for more than just the equation environment might be easier using Text::Balanced too.
my @equations;
my $current_equation = '';
while(<$fh>) {
  my $test;
  next unless ($test = /\\begin\{equation\}/ .. /\\end\{equation\}/);

  if ($test !~ /(^1|E0)$/ ) {
    chomp;
    $current_equation .= $_;
  } elsif ($test =~ /E0$/) {
    #print $current_equation . "\n";
    push @equations, {eq => $current_equation};
    $current_equation = '';
  }
}

foreach my $eq (@equations) {
  print "Full Equation: " . $eq->{'eq'} . "\n";
  solve($eq);
  print "Result: " . $eq->{'value'} . "\n\n";
}

sub solve {
  my $eq = shift;

  print $eq->{'eq'} . "\n";

  parse($eq);
  compute($eq);

  print "intermediate result: " . $eq->{'value'} . "\n";
}

sub parse {
  my $eq = shift;

  my ($command,@fields) = extract_multiple(
    $eq->{'eq'}, [ sub { extract_bracketed(shift,'{}') } ]
  );

  $command =~ s/^\\//;
  print "command: " . $command . "\n";

  @fields = map { s/^\{\ *//; s/\ *\}$//; print "arg: $_\n"; {value => $_}; } @fields;


  ($eq->{'command'}, @{ $eq->{'args'} }) = ($command, @fields);
}

sub compute {
  my ($eq) = @_;

  #check arguements ...
  foreach my $arg (@{$eq->{'args'}}) {
    #if arguement is a number, continue
    if ($arg->{'value'} =~ /^$re_num$/) {
      next;

    #if the arguement is a simple mathematical operation, do it and continue
    } elsif ($arg->{'value'} =~ /^($re_num)\ *(?:\ |\*|\\times)?\ *($re_num)$/) {
      $arg->{'value'} = $1 * $2;
    } elsif ($arg->{'value'} =~ /^($re_num)\ *(?:\+)?\ *($re_num)$/) {
      $arg->{'value'} = $1 + $2;
    } elsif ($arg->{'value'} =~ /^($re_num)\ *(?:\-)?\ *($re_num)$/) {
      $arg->{'value'} = $1 - $2;
    } elsif ($arg->{'value'} =~ /^($re_num)\ *(?:\/)?\ *($re_num)$/) {
      $arg->{'value'} = $1 / $2;
    } else {
      #parse it and calc it as if it were its own equation.
      $arg->{'eq'} = $arg->{'value'};
      solve($arg);
    }
  }

  my @args = @{$eq->{'args'}};

  ## add command processing here
  # frac
  if ($eq->{'command'} eq 'frac') {
    $eq->{'value'} = $args[0]->{'value'} / $args[1]->{'value'};
    return;
  }

}
```

and here is a sample test.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Hello World!

\begin{equation}
\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using `boost::spirit` in order to tokenize the expression. You will need to define a huge grammar!

Comment: ...where `while (true) { huge *= huge; }` is defined and observable behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Use a parser generator to create an appropriate parser. Try ANTLR for this, as it includes an IDE for the Grammar, which is very helpful. Using tree rewrite rules, you can then convert the parse tree to an abstract syntax tree.

Start perhaps with the expression evaluator from ANTLR tutorial. I think this is reasonably close enough.